# Инициализация auto переменных в c++

Tags: c++

Как инициализировать переменную типа `auto` при помощи ввода с клавиатуры ?
Я могу сделать так:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x
```

или так:

```
double y;
std::cin >> y;
```

Но например я хочу ввести число с клавиатуры и не знаю, буду ли я вводить целое число или дробное. На ум приходит только это:

```
auto x;
std::cin >> x;
```

Но так не компилируется.

Comment: Указать нужный тип :)

Comment: Ввести на клавиатуре после `auto`: backspace (4 раза), потом `i`, `n` и `t` ... А вообще, вопрос требует чуть больше описания проблемы.

Comment: правильней всего будет `double x;
std::cin >> x;`

Comment: @αλεχολυτ вопрос уточнил)

Comment: Вводите как строку, анализируйте, далее используйте структуру с указанием типа и его введенным значением. Только такой подход приведет к никому не нужной и сложной программе.

Answer (score 6):

`auto` принимает тип присваиваемого выражения, который должен быть очевиден компилятору ещё до исполнения.

В вашем примере auto вообще не инициализируется никаким выражением, оно просто объявляется, а далее просто идут инструкции cin, поэтому компилятор не знает какой тип туда определить.

В данном случае, тип ввода нужно будет определить вручную, динамически, т.к. вы заранее не знаете какой будет ввод.